# How to pick a sampling time When merging 2 files with different sampling time (very close)?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 text files containing the same information (same structure) but they are obtained in slightly different sampling time. The reason for merging them is that one of them is missing some data (it misses the data for some time).

The problem when I merge them using unique function the data is taken for both of them, I want to ignore one of them if the data is available in both.

Comment: Can you provide brief examples of your data? What do the variables look like that you fed to `unique`? See [mre].

Comment: 1. merge. 2. sort by sampling time. 3. find unique index of sampling time with the second output of _unique_. 4. index the merged data.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear. Can you please edit your post to include runnable code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: https:
//we.tl
/t-d7wNwN2Y57

example is in the previous link, i couldnt attach it to the question please note that i have put spaces in the link so that i can post it here.

Comment: ( i entered a space after https:    and a space after we.tl)

Comment: Please do what @FragileX asks and edit your question to include example code, preferably no more than necessary to demonstrate the issue. Also if you can include a sample of the two text files that would be useful. This is the minimum amount of effort you need to do if you want someone to help you.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I will answer the question. All you asked sample of data and all code files are in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i went with the idea of deleting all the rows of one of the files once the time in second file starts. For example file 1 contains the data from time 0 to 100 and the second file contains time from 9 to 150. Then just specify the time 9 and delete the rows of file 1 from time 9 and above. No problem in this case if the frequency is a liitle bit different.as long as the plots are generally the same.